# A cyclic system of cubic equations

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, cubics

I would like to solve the following system of equations over the real numbers:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
x + y^2 + z^3 &=& 3\\
y + z^2 + x^3 &=& 3\\
z + x^2 + y^3 &=& 3\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
According to Mathematica there is only one solution, $(x, y, z) = (1, 1, 1)$. I can show that for all other solutions, $x$, $y$ and $z$ would have to be (pairwise) distinct, so I can assume $x < y <z$ or $x < z <y$, but that's all I have so far. I'm mainly interested in real solutions, but I would also like to know if there are any other complex solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I expect there are a lot ($27$, counting multiplicities) of solutions in $\Bbb C$. For starters, there are the two complex solutions $x=y=z=-1\pm\sqrt{-2}$.

Comment: Is it always the case that the number of complex solutions to a system of polynomial equations is at most equal to the product of the biggest exponent in each equation?

Comment: no, for example consider the system $y^2 = 1 ; x+y^2 = 2$

Comment: Yes, but my question was if it is an upper bound to the number of solutions, not necessarily equal to it.

Answer (score 1):

$x,y,z$ are roots of the degree $27$ polynomial

$x^{27}-27x^{24}+317x^{21}-18x^{19}-2067x^{18}-50x^{17}+279x^{16}+8156x^{15}+645x^{14}-1674x^{13}-20359x^{12}-3044x^{11}+4645x^{10}+33644x^9 + 6288x^8-6388x^7-36936x^6-5925x^5+4957x^4+23187x^3+4063x^2-4342x-5352$

[image]

The triangles show how to pick $(x,z,y)$ to form solutions (I think I messed up the ordering)

$1$ is indeed the only real root.

Comment: Thank you for your calculations, this is pretty good evidence. I'm gonna wait another day before I accept your answer, I'm hoping for a simple analytic solution :).

Comment: If  $\max{|x|,|y|,|z|} = m \ge 3$ then we get $3 \ge m^3 - (m+m^2) \ge 15$, which is impossible so you're left with $[-3;3]^3$ which is compact. If you look for other all-positive solutions and look carefully at when $x \to x^2$ increases or decreases, you'll notice that you need either $x,y,z \ge 1$ or $x,y,z \le 1$ (or else you get $3 \lt 3$ somewhere), so this removes $1/8$th of the possibilities. Then by compactness you can brute-force a proof only with simple inequalities simply by looking at random points and finding small open cubes around them where there can't be any solution.